# Post data in a specific div on other page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to know if I can `post` a data in a form to a specific div on other page. Let say example,

**form.php**

I have this code in jQuery:

```
$("#hod").change(function(){
        var hod = $('#hod').val();
        $.post('calc.php #content',
        {
            hod : hod
        }, function(data){
            $('#designation').html(data)
        });
    });
```

**calc.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['budget'])){
    $budget=$_POST['budget'];
    $paid=$_POST['paid'];
    $ammount=$_POST['ammount'];
    $gst=$_POST['gst']; 
}
$total=$budget+$paid+$ammount+$gst;
echo $total;
?>

<div id="content">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['hod'])){
    $hod=$_POST['hod'];
}
require '../db_connection/connection-intra.php';
$sql="SELECT s.nama,s.staff_id,gp.jawatan,j.nama_jabatan from staff s INNER JOIN gred_pekerja gp ON s.gred_id=gp.gred_id INNER JOIN jabatan j ON j.j_id=s.j_id WHERE s.staff_id='$hod'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(!$result) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
} 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $jawatan=$row['jawatan'];
        $jabatan=$row['nama_jabatan'];
    }
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
echo $jawatan." ".$jabatan;
?>
</div>
```

If I send the `post` value to page **calc.php**, it will also take the value outside of the `<div id="content"></div>`. Is there a way to only send the content on the `<div>`

Comment: Where is `#hod`? You could use `strip_tags()` on `calc.php`.

Comment: The problem is your returned document is not a valid HTML document in itself so you might have trouble parsing it as such to extract just the content div. At the risk of triggering the wrath of Zalgo, have you considered using a regular expression to extract that block?

Comment: If you don't want to show the value outside of the `div`, don't `echo` anything before or after it.

Comment: Thanks for the details guys. Will try it